# Wordpress $wpdb->get_results returns only one row

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress

I'm totally confused.
I run 2 the same queries, one with $wpdb, the other via mysql_query (also checked via phpmyadmin)
First query returns ONLY ONE row:

```
$wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_terms WHERE slug LIKE '%info%' ORDER BY name ASC");
```

mysl_query returns 42 rows. The same result if run the query via phpmyadmin.

```
$con=mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD);
  mysql_selectdb(DB_NAME,$con);
  $res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wp_terms WHERE slug LIKE  '%info%' ORDER BY name ASC",$con);
  while($obj=mysql_fetch_object($res)) {
    var_dump($obj);
  }
```

How can it be ??

```
$wpdb->show_errors();
$wpdb->print_error();
```

show no errors.

Comment: Just a thought - you have tried disabling all plugins, right? Can you also add `define('SAVEQUERIES', true);` in your wp-config.php and then  add `echo "<pre>"; print_r($wpdb->queries); echo "</pre>";` after your query.

Comment: * tip instead of `wp_terms` use `$wpdb->prefix . 'terms'` Or with default tables use `$wpdb->terms` http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Tables

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->terms WHERE slug LIKE '%info%' ORDER BY name ASC", ARRAY_A );
```

Do you have plugins that might interfere with the database?